# call server's webpage by its hostname rather IP address

Tags: apache, http, webserver

I have setup apache webserver in my Linux server (redhat-8, to be used locally). It has a static IP address.
I can call its HTML webpage by its IP address but now I want to call this webpage by name rather an IP address i.e http://www.myserver.com or any other name if I cant use .com.

Tried a lots of solution available on internet but couldn't browse my server's webpage by its name (myserver.com)

P.S.-> Server is to be used  only on intranet (locally) so I don't think it is necessary to get my local IP address and name (myserver.com) registered with DNS. myserver.com is my server's host name.

```
$hostname
myserver.com
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: The client (i.e. the system with the browser) needs to know what IP address is associated to the domain name.  If not from the dns, then from a local host file.  Then in Apache, your VirtualHost needs to be setup to respond to that specific name on the desired port (80 here since you do not have https).  The name should be defined in the local host file of the server system (i.e. where Apache is installed) as well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
could you please be little more elaborative. Which files exactly I have to modify and where?